# How to integrate biometric fingerprint authentication in Angular 4 with asp.net core web application?

Tags: angular

I am developing a web application using Angular 4 with ASP.NET Core 2.I want to implement biometric fingerprint authentication on login in my application.How to integrate/communicate fingerprint device with angular 4 we application?